# Run two while loops one after another taking user input

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

In my method i want user input if it passes first while it need to go to second while loop, in second while if the condition fails it need to re-run the loop but instead of re-running itself, the first while is being executed.

```
//Method to read, validate and store postcode and purchase amount for N customers
public  void addRecord(int customerCounter) throws IOException
{
    int postcode;
    double purchaseAmount;

    int conform =0;

    do{
        BufferedReader breader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Postcode: ");
        postcode= Integer.parseInt(breader.readLine());

        if(4121 >postcode)
        {
            System.out.print("Postcode must be greater than 4121");
            System.out.print("Try again: ");                            
        }
        else if(postcode > 4123)
        {
            System.out.print("Postcode must be less than 4123");
            System.out.print("Try again: ");                            
        }
        else
        {
            conform = 1;
            //System.out.println(conform);
        }
    }
    while(4121 >postcode && postcode > 4123);



    if(conform == 1)
    {
        System.out.println(conform);
        do
        {
            BufferedReader breader2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            breader2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Purchase Amount: ");
            purchaseAmount= Double.parseDouble(breader2.readLine());

            if(purchaseAmount < 60)
            {
                System.out.print("Purchase Amount must be greater than $60");
                System.out.print("Try again: ");
                continue;
            }
            else if(purchaseAmount > 500)
            {
                System.out.print("Purchase Amount must be greater than $500");
                System.out.print("Try again: ");                                                
            }           
        }
        while(purchaseAmount < 60 && purchaseAmount > 500);         

    }   

}
```

Comment: Actually every thing is running as per requirement, my only problem is that when 2nd while matches the condition every starts from the beginning, not by asking only purchaseAmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions in the `while` are wrong, they will always be false

```
postcode = 5000;
while(postcode < 4121 && postcode > 4123); -> while(false && true); -> false

postcode = 3000;
while(postcode < 4121 && postcode > 4123); -> while(true && false); -> false
```

Use OR instead of AND

```
while(postcode < 4121 || postcode > 4123);
```

Same goes for the second while.

The second execution of the first while is probably because you call `addRecord` again.

Comment: My while condition as always giving out false. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use 2 nested infinite loops.

In this way the program checks only 2 times the postcode and the price inserted for each loop to determine if can go forward, instead of 4 times in the your solution.

```
//Method to read, validate and store postcode and purchase amount for N customers
public  void addRecord(int customerCounter) throws IOException
{
    int postcode;
    double purchaseAmount;

    int conform =0;

    do{
        BufferedReader breader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Postcode: ");
        postcode= Integer.parseInt(breader.readLine());

        if(4121 >postcode)
        {
            System.out.print("Postcode must be greater than 4121");
            System.out.print("Try again: ");                            
        }
        else if(postcode > 4123)
        {
            System.out.print("Postcode must be less than 4123");
            System.out.print("Try again: ");                            
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(conform);
            do{

                BufferedReader breader2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                breader2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println("Purchase Amount: ");
                purchaseAmount= Double.parseDouble(breader2.readLine());

                if(purchaseAmount < 60)
                {
                    System.out.print("Purchase Amount must be greater than $60");
                    System.out.print("Try again");
                    continue;
                 }
                 else if(purchaseAmount > 500)
                 {
                     System.out.print("Purchase Amount must be greater than $500");
                     System.out.print("Try again");                                                
                 }else{
                     break;
                 }

             }while(true);
             break;
        }
    }
    while(true);

}
```

Comment: I tried the sample provide by you but when i enter wrong price  it again starts from 1st loop. To make it clear my requirement is that if user enter wrong price program should display price  screen not start from beginning.